# what are memory fractions and how to get rid of them (or the sort operator) in the example below?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

[This execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rygIKjCdm) has the following memory fractions:
`Memory fraction input:1, Memory Fraction Output:1.`

it is a very simple query:

```
SELECT                  [a].[activityId],
                        [a].[title],
                        [a].[description],
                        [a].[inclusions],
                        [d].[path],
                        [d].[uploadToBucket],
                        [a].[imageUriMain],
                        [a].[locationId]
FROM                    [dbo].[activity]                AS a
LEFT JOIN               [dbo].[document]                AS d 
       ON d.documentId = a.documentId 
      AND d.activityId = a.activityId

ORDER BY                title                           ASC
```

what are memory fractions and how to get rid of them (or the sort operator) in the above example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a look at the properties of the sort operator:
it has [MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlqueryprocessing/2010/03/11/mystery-of-memory-fraction-in-showplan-xml/)

[image]

getting rid of this sort operation

having a look at the indexes and definition of table `dbo.activity`
there are no `nonclustered indexes` only the primary key

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[activity] ( 
[activityId]      INT              IDENTITY(1,1)                 NOT NULL,
[title]           VARCHAR(100)                     NOT NULL,
[description]     VARCHAR(max)                     NOT NULL,
[inclusions]      VARCHAR(max)                         NULL,
[imageUriMain]    VARCHAR(255)                         NULL,
[imageUriThumb]   VARCHAR(255)                         NULL,
[imageUriTeaser]  VARCHAR(255)                         NULL,
[categoryId]      INT                              NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT [DF__activity__catego__0F975522] DEFAULT ((1)),
[locationId]      INT                                  NULL,
[documentId]      INT                                  NULL,
CONSTRAINT   [PK_activity]  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED    ([activityId] asc),
CONSTRAINT   [FK_activity_category]                         FOREIGN KEY ([categoryId]) REFERENCES [ref_activityCategory]([categoryId]),
CONSTRAINT   [FK_activity_location]                         FOREIGN KEY ([locationId]) REFERENCES [location]([locationId]))

GO
```

same with table `documents`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[document] ( 
[documentId]      INT              IDENTITY(1,1)                 NOT NULL,
[uploadToBucket]  VARCHAR(200)                         NULL,
[path]            VARCHAR(200)                         NULL,
[activityId]      INT                                  NULL,
CONSTRAINT   [PK__document__EFAAAD856EBBBDCD]  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED    ([documentId] asc))
```

I create the following indexes (paying attention to the `order by` and all the needed columns for this query):

```
create index I_title_01 on [dbo].[activity] 
(title asc,documentId  asc,activityid asc)
INCLUDE(
        [description],
        [inclusions],
        [imageUriMain],
        [locationId]
)
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, --drop_existing=on,
DATA_COMPRESSION=page, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES


create index I_doc_01 on [dbo].[document] 
(documentId  asc,activityid asc)
INCLUDE(
                            [path],
                            [uploadToBucket]
)
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
 --drop_existing=on,
DATA_COMPRESSION=page, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES
```

And now [the new execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ4Gf2AO7) looks like this (without `sort operation`):

[image]

Regarding what are memory fractions, I get my answer from this site below, which has explanations and even examples:

[Batch mode memory fractions](https://orderbyselectnull.com/2018/02/15/batch-mode-memory-fractions/)

> There’s very little information out there about memory fractions. I
>   would define them as information in the query plan that can give you
>   clues about each operator’s share of the total query memory grant.
>   This is naturally more complicated for query plans that insert into
>   tables with columnstore indexes but that won’t be covered here. Most
>   references will tell you not to worry about memory fractions or that
>   they aren’t useful most of the time. Out of thousands of queries that
>   I’ve tuned I can only think of a few for which memory fractions were
>   relevant. Sometimes queries spill to tempdb even though SQL Server
>   reports that a lot of query memory was unused. In these situations I
>   generally hope for a poor cardinality estimate which leads to a memory
>   fraction which is too low for the spilling operator. If fixing the
>   cardinality estimate doesn’t prevent the spill then things can get a
>   lot more complicated, assuming that you don’t just give up.